checkbox not rendering based on database value
I have a pop up box where one column has checkboxes, to see whether the the item has been published or not. I want the checkboxes to appear with its current state in the database while rendering. There is a field in backend called in_draft. (If its false , then the checkbox should be ticked,  and vice versa). Only if a user check the blank checkbox, I want it to update to in_draft goes from True to False..I tried the following code,
but initially the checkboxes are appearing blank. When I click on any one
of them, it publised it, but after logging out and going to that pop up boxes,
all are blank...but in backend it is updated.
The code of foucs here is .....
<td class="text-center">
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="selectedReports" :value="report.id" 
                @change="handleCheckboxChange(report.id, $event.target.checked)"/>
    </td>

The async function is here:
async handleCheckboxChange(reportId, isChecked) {
      console.log("Checkbox changed:", { reportId, isChecked });
      this.isUpdating = true;
      try {
        if (isChecked) {
          console.log("Checkbox checked. Report ID:", reportId);
          
          // Check if the report is already in the selectedReports list
          if (!this.selectedReports.includes(reportId)) {
            
            this.selectedReports.push(reportId);
          } else {
            // console.log("Report already in selectedReports.");
          }

          // Publish the report if checked
          
          await this.$repository.studyReports.edit({ in_draft: false }, reportId);
          // console.log("Report published successfully.");
          this.$toast.success('Report published successfully.');
        } else {
          // console.log("Checkbox unchecked. Report ID:", reportId);
          
          // Remove the report from the selectedReports list
          if (this.selectedReports.includes(reportId)) {
            // console.log("Removing report from selectedReports.");
            this.selectedReports = this.selectedReports.filter(id => id !== reportId);
          } else {
            // console.log("Report not found in selectedReports.");
          }
        }
      } catch (error) {
        // console.error("Error in handleCheckboxChange:", error);
        this.$toast.error(`Error: ${error.response?.data?.error || error.message}`);
      } finally {
        // console.log("Resetting isUpdating flag.");
        this.isUpdating = false;
      }
    }

This is export part
export default {
  name: "ManageStudyReportsModal",
  components: { StudyReportEditForm, StudyReportForm },
  data() {
    return {
      addCollapse: null,
      editCollapse: null,
      isUpdating: false,
      studyreports: [],
      selectedReports: [], // IDs of the selected reports
      meta: {
        totalItems: 0,
        totalPages: 0,
        currentPage: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
      },
      report: null,
    };
  },


how is selectedReports: [] related to what's in the database?

Also its not good to use v-model and :value together as v-model will provide two way binding and :value will provide one way binding. So, if using v-model it will auto update the data on change, but if using :value you need to explicitly update the changes to the variable.

@YashMaheshwari - a type=checkbox value isn't the same as a type=text value

You need to update the input to something like <input type="checkbox" :value="selectedReports.includes(report.id)" @change="handleCheckboxChange(report.id, $event.target.checked)"/> and I think it will work, considering that the values are correctly updated.

@JaromandaX but still my point regarding the usage of v-modal and value together is a valid one, I think.

except it's not a valid point with checkboxes (and radios and selects)

:value="selectedReports.includes(report.id)" also incorrect, since the value has nothing to do with the state of the checkbox

just letting you know: async function is inside the export part. can you two suggest some answers?

the fact that the async function is inside the export part does not change the issues mentioned above

The only issue is that when the component loads, the selectedReports will be an empty array, therefore all checkboxes that use selectedReports will be unchecked - by the way, I learned something in this question ... never realised what using an array as the v-model for multiple v-model does

Then, there should be a way to to show checked without creating an array called selected Reports... I mean why go to selectreports first, the template at the top should have checked boxes...before calling async function...No?
